# div into li hover toggle animation

Tags: jquery, html

the problem is this: there is a list, in this list div. When i point to li div must translated from display: none to display: block. As he must appear with efekt animation (from right to left appears div). The problem is that when I put up the script standing, then when i hover on li the block appears and disappears so constantly repeated. It is necessary that when i move the unit appeared and stood until I can not move the cursor away from the li, and I get that the unit constantly appears and disappears.

```
<ul>
   <li class="link">
      <span><i>3</i>МЕСТО</span>
      <div class="images">
         <img src="images/place_img1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="hover">
         <span><i>3</i>МЕСТО</span>
         <p>MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, iMac либо сертификат на аренду «заряженной» машины на 24 часа, либо 48 часов. Например: Nissan GTR alpha 12, Мерседес C класс 6,3 AMG либо BMW M5
         </p>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>



$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".link").hover(function () {
     $(".hover").stop().toggle("slide", {}, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: What are you asking? Please edit your question to make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right you wanted such functionality that if you hover li element then .hover div opens and if your cursor leaves then .hover div closes.

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/g241nezo/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".link").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find(".hover").toggle();
    })
        .mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find(".hover").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: yes but this not working with .toggle ("slide", {}, 1000); and I need the same animation or similar